# "Open with... Vim" does not load _vimrc settings

Tags: windows, vim, gvim, vimrc

I use Vim (gVim to be precise) to write and edit files. When executing the editor directly, everything works fine. But if I open a file using the "Open with..." command on Windows, the `_vimrc` settings do not load.

How can I fix this ?

**EDIT**
I added the `_gvimrc` file as well, but it doesn't seem to do any better.

Comment: Where are those `_vimrc` and `_gvimrc`?

Comment: They're at `$VIM/*`, which is, in my case, `Programs/Vim/*`.

Comment: They shouldn't. Their correct location is `$HOME\_vimrc` and `$HOME\_vimrc`. And put your plugins in `$HOME\vimfiles`. If you have 7.4, you should put your `_vimrc` and `_gvimrc` in `$HOME\vimfiles`.

Comment: THey could be, though. Vim looks there too. That does not explain why Vim wouldn't look there. One thought: do you have multiple installed versions of Vim? Perhaps the "open with..." dialog is using a different version than you expect.

Comment: @Ben (Note I don't have a copy of windows) On my computer `vim --version` tell me the location that vim will search for vimrc files. `$VIM/vimrc` is where the system vimrc can be found. Most likely it is similar to that on Windows. Notice that it is vimrc and NOT _vimrc or .vimrc. So vim won't read `$VIM\_vimrc` on its own.

Comment: @romainl Would it be correct to say you should remove the leading underscores when placing in `$HOME\vimfiles`?

Comment: @FDinoff, Sorry, yes you are right: that's vimrc and not _vimrc.

Comment: Actually on Windows, $VIM/_vimrc and $VIM/_gvimrc ARE sourced. That is actually where the installer places the default _vimrc when you choose to create one. `:help vimrc` actually tells you this explicitly.

Comment: Thanks everybody ! @Ben, no this is the sole version of Vim installed on my machine. And what's the difference between `vimrc` and `_vimrc` ?

Comment: `$HOME\vimfiles\vimrc` is an alternate location for your Vim config; it is just like `$VIM\_vimrc` but in a more convenient spot. So to your problem: how do you know the settings aren't loading? Some tools to help: (1) use `:scriptnames` to see what scripts have been sourced and in which order. Your _vimrc should be in there somewhere. (2) use `:verbose set optionname?` to see the current value of an option and where it was last set. Similarly for maps: `:verbose map {keys}` tells you where a mapping for {keys} was set.

Comment: @Ben : thank you so much ! Thanks to `:verbose set optionname?` I was able to detect that the settings were loaded `vimrc_example`. I deleted that file and the `source $VIMRUNTIME/vimrc_example` in my `_vimrc` and everything is fine now. Thanks you !